# Flask ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: python, node.js, web, flask

I'm trying to access a local webserver (Flask) from an iPad. 
my setup: iPad connected via Ethernet to a Macbook (server). 
When I try a Node.js (express) webserver - as seen bellow - it works, I can access `http://172.x.x.x:5000/` and get the response. However when I try the same thing with a simple Flask server I can't access it, I get the error `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` on iPad (Chrome browser).

Simple Node.js server that works:

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
var PORT = 5000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ value: 1 }));
})

app.listen(PORT);
```

Flask (Python) server that works locally but not from iPad:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=False)
```

Detail: if I add ssl_context to flask (`app.run(ssl_context='adhoc'`) it works on the iPad, however I don't have credentials and get the error of unsecure webpage, so request to the REST API don't work.

obs: I can't run node.js on production.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's about something core origins. You must handle in your code. Cross domain access try to read about it.

Comment: yes, I added CORS, and the error remains the same. 
Also I get the log on Flask: 
```172.16.0.49 - - [14/Nov/2019 11:10:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -```
meaning that the connection is ok, flask session is receiving the call from remote device.

Comment: I also disabled the firewall on MacOS, the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

So, if anyone in the future encounters this error, I couldn't find a fix.. however I found a simple work around: to have a Node.js Proxy Script proxying info from Flask to the iPad:

```
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

try {
    var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        try {
            proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://10.0.60.108:10800' });
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(`[PROXY]-> ERROR!`);
        }
    });


    server.listen(5001);
    console.log("[PROXY]-> PORT:5001")
} catch (error) {
    //handle errors here
    console.log('[PROXY]:error')
}
```